# How to output disk size in GB only with no rounding error?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, bash, partitioning

Output disk size in GB only.  Giga Bytes only.
Not MB.  Not Mega Bytes.
Not TB.  Not Tera Bytes.

Tested thus far:

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda`
1000204886016

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}'` 
1000.2

`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}' |numfmt --field=1- --format=%.0f --invalid=ignore`
1001

But above `1001` output is a rounding error.
`1000` is ideal output, meaning `1000 GB` disk size.

Question1:
How to fix above rounding error?

Question2:
What is a more elegant way or shorter way versus 120 characters below:
`sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |bc -l |awk '{print $1/1000000000}' |numfmt --field=1- --format=%.0f --invalid=ignore`

.
.

using:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64

--

Comment: check this https://www.baeldung.com/linux/round-divided-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking it's not a rounding error *under the rounding method used by numfmt,* of which there are several. You need to choose the rounding behavior you want, likely `--round=nearest` for the one most people expect:

```
   --round=METHOD
          use METHOD for rounding when scaling; METHOD can be: up,
          down, from-zero (default), towards-zero, nearest
```

But as you only want a specific unit (GB), numfmt is completely redundant here after you've already done the division using awk – all it does for you is add the 'G', and you can already do that from awk itself, as well as use awk's own float (or even integer) formatting where `%.0f` always uses nearest rounding (and `%d` truncates).

```
$ blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda | awk '{printf("%.0f GB\n", $1/1000000000)}'
1000 GB
```

The `bc -l` appears to be redundant in your example since you're not actually doing any operations within 'bc', but you *could* use it as well:

```
$ sz=$(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda); echo "$sz/1000000000" | bc
```

You can also use Bash's integer arithmetic within `$(( ... ))` or `$[...]` (identical but the latter is non­standard) if truncation (rounding down) is good enough:

```
$ sz=$(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda); echo "$[sz/1000000000]G"
```

Comment: small changes to answer by u1686_grawity :  
```sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda |awk '{printf("%.0fG\n", $1/1000000000)}'```  
outputs desired 5 characters ```1000G``` .